Does the q-DHI assumption work in a multilinear map?
I want to know that if the q-BDHI which works in a bilinear map can be extended to a multilinear map situation. Concretely, given $L=(g, g^a, g^{a^2},...,g^{a^q})$, there exists a negiligible functon negl(·) such that for all $\lambda \in$ N

$ Pr[\mathcal{A}(\lambda, L)=e(g,g,...,g)^{1/a}]\leq negl(\lambda)$

The definition of q-decisional "bilinear" Diffie-Hellman Inversion assumption is:

Here is the Diffie-Hellman Inversion assumption in multilinear map without q-type:


We found the assumption in this paper, which is called (l,k) Multilinear Diffie Hellman Inversion Assumption
